# Corporations in the lead in space

Tags: science-fiction, space

In a world where space travel isn't a problem and systems are connected by travel gates, new systems are often explored and the galaxy (our galaxy) is populated by humans all over. A lot of corporations exist and a lot of them are huge. There are such as: Mining corporations, space-security, space-constructions, exploration agencies, space labs (huge companies galaxywide), terraforming corps, settle and resettle companies, galaxy bank corps, fleet building corps, and others.

Which corporation(s) could probably be in the lead and have high authority over others and rule the galaxy?

If more info is required I'm eager to share.

Edit: All space vessels use N-energy as fuel (neutrino). Travel gates are controllable worm holes around which a station is built. The gates are linked 1=1. The Gates are massive, about the size of Pluto, but what I mean by gates is just two Bracket-like columns on either side of a worm hole. Out traffic goes in the left column which is labeled "Out" and in traffic comes from the side of the right column which is signed "In".

Comment: Do the spaceships or the travel gates require some kind of standardised fuel?

Comment: How big are the Gates?  Human size or super cargo container spaceship size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## He who controls the spice, controls the universe.

Or in this case, wormholes. Anybody who controls a wormhole controls exactly who is or isn't allowed to travel. Get on the bad side of Wormhole Corp? Well, better hope you don't need anything on the other side of their wormholes.

If there are governments, they're likely going to control their own core wormholes and forcibly seize any critical arteries. So you're unlikely to see a core area controlled by a mega corporation that hasn't already supplanted the government.

However, out on the fringes... whoever gets to own and operate the wormholes, be they an exploration firm or a terraforming conglomerate, essentially gets massive control over all the resources discovered on the other end. Even regulations can only go so far - paperwork can get lost for the wrong people easily, costing them valuable time to take advantage of the new space.

Thus you're going to see wormhole gate owning companies in the ruling positions, and jockeying to take and develop a potentially valuable wormhole.

Comment: I was thinking that resource mining corps could be in the lead, but your idea is good. What about fleet-building corps?

Comment: @SovereignSun Fleet builders don't have any intrinsic advantage on this front - your wormholes are the limited resources, so they're going to be powerful if they can get hold of a useful one, else not.

Answer (score 2):

The most powerful corporations will depend on several factors, but the main factor is simply supply and demand. So, the largest corporations are ones that control industries with low supply and proportionally high demand. Here are some real-world examples:

**Very low supply, relatively high demand**: Think gold, diamonds, designer clothes, large banks, etc. The amount of these items are very limited, often artificially, but that does not stop people from spending a lot of money on the few companies that make them.

**Decent supply, incredibly high demand**: Think oil and practical technology, like computers. Although oil is very plentiful in many areas(Middle East, US, Venezuela, Azerbaijan, etc.) if an area doesn't have oil, they *NEED* to get it from whoever owns it, giving them a lot of control. Likewise, certain technologies that are used by nearly everybody but are only built by a few companies(Microsoft, Apple) will give those companies a good amount of power *IF* they can keep their technological edge.

**Variable supply, constant demand**: Think transportation and communications. Letters can be lost, trucks can crash, internet can be slow. Whoever an provide these services in a cheap and reliable way, such as Amazon, or can get create barriers to potentially better competition, like Comcast, will be in high demand. These types companies have the added bonus of being critical to other companies: it doesn't matter how much oil you have if you can't ship it to customers.

So, to put this into examples in your world: if the N-energy fuel is only found on a few planets, the owners of those planets will be powerful. If the fuel is very volatile and difficult to transport, whoever can transport it reliably will be powerful. If the gates require advanced technology to build and maintain, whoever designs that tech will be powerful.